# Module not found error because path is interpreted as module

Tags: python, anaconda

I have downloaded a package with the following general structure:

```
 - pkg
   - runs
     - __init__.py
     - script.py
   - data
     - subdata
       - __init__.py
       - datascript.py
```

When I try to run `script.py` from the Anaconda prompt using

```
C:\pkg>python runs/script.py
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runs/script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from data.subdata import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data.subdata'
```

so apparently, python is interpreting `data.subdata` as a module instead of a path.

How can I fix that?

Comment: add the path in sys.path ->sys.path.append('path_to_data')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the path in sys.path ->`sys.path.append('path_to_module')`

- import statements search through the list of paths in sys.path
- sys.path always includes the path of the script invoked on the
  command line and is agnostic to the working directory on the command line.
- importing a package is conceptually the same as importing that
  package’s **init**.py file

read more :
https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html

Comment: So I have to do sys.path.append('data/subdata')  because the import statement is from data.subdata import *  ?

Comment: Since the package comes with __init__py files (see pkg structure in the question), isnt there another way to do this? I find it extremely cumbersome to add each path for each module to sys.path and it doesnt even work.

Comment: have u consider to open above link, please do i found "Converting a folder of scripts into an importable package of modules" helpful

Comment: Please can you give an example for "sys.path always includes the path of the script invoked on the command line and is agnostic to the working directory on the command line"?